# Dark Matter/Energy & Space-Time

Tags: cosmology, gravity, newtonian-gravity, dark-matter, dark-energy

After searching for quite a while for a minimalist approach to explaining Dark Matter as well as Dark Energy, unfortunately without much good, I decided I may as well help fill the explored paths, or at least introduce a different viewpoint. Before you begin reading the questions, expect them to be very simple, in particular, they come from observations of the effects of space-time curvature. Before answering, I suggest reading all questions, rather than answering for each, as they are a connected whole.

So here are my **questions** to some common problems related to Dark Matter or Dark Energy (**P**roblem & **Q**uestion):

1. P: Observations of the matter within a galaxy shows that the speed at which it orbits around the center is relatively uniform rather than dipping down as it gets farther away [(Source)](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/%7Eryden/ast162_7/notes30.html).

- Q: Does dark matter exacerbate the effects of gravity? If so, could this be explained in terms of space-time itself rather than a form of matter? In other words, how does the stretching of space-time, such as the expansion of the universe, affect gravity?

2. P: The matter at the beginning of the universe, the first epoch, decoupled from radiation, and thus began clumping together, faster than expected [(Source)](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Eejchaisson/cosmic_evolution/docs/text/text_part_3.html).

- Q: What effect of dark matter is assisting in the decoupling? What was the shape and/or size of the space-time which contained the matter during this time? Was the effective space smaller compared to now?

3. P: The universe is expanding at an increasing rate, that is to say, the expansion of the universe increases over time due to some parameter [(Source)](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2019/mystery-of-the-universe-s-expansion-rate-widens-with-new-hubble-data). In tandem, this expansion is not uniformly distributed throughout the universe [(Source)](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/universe-s-expansion-may-not-be-the-same-in-all-directions.html).

- Q: Is this increasing expansion an acceleration? Does the distribution of the expansion negatively correlate with energy density? That is to say, is it higher for more isolated areas?

4. P: Some cases studied in cosmology, such as that of the Bullet Cluster, show that the center of mass can be separate from the visible mass [(Source)](https://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2006/1e0657/).

- Q: Is this phenomenon seen in smaller bodies of mass, such as the coalescence of two super-massive blackholes? How does space-time curve or change when two bodies of matter, particularly large ones, collide or move past each other? Is the change in shape instant?

You could probably guess, but some of these are leading questions, mostly included as a way to introduce the thought process, and otherwise as a means to encourage skepticism (and overall engagement).

Question #3 is what sparked my main interest in trying to simplify dark matter and/or dark energy. The concept is such that, rather than being a separate particle or form, it is a result of the physics of space-time. Of course, this probably sounds almost like a conspiracy to a physics enthusiast, however it doesn't have quite as much depth. It is commonly taught that space-time is like a sheet or cloth, a flat, somewhat bouncy material. The proposal in this case, is that it is more like a fluid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please post one question per post. Also, why do you want to simplify dark energy and dark matter? Aren't dark energy described by cosmological constant and dark matter explained by the CDM simple enough?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that dark energy is explained by cosmological constant, however I do agree that dark matter can be explained by CDM. The reasons for simplifying the concepts is such that I feel they could be unified. Rather than setting up dark matter and dark energy as something more complex, the idea is to formulate an inherent function of space time, like entropy (although personally I think something like the expansion *is* due to entropy).

Answer (score 1):

> Q1 How does the stretching of space-time affect gravity?

In general relativity the “stretching” (or, better, the curvature) of spacetime *is* gravity. Both dark matter and ordinary matter/energy curve spacetime and so create gravitational fields.

> Q2 What effect of dark matter is assisting in the decoupling?

By “decoupling” I assume you mean the clumping together of matter to form the very first stars and galaxies. Once again the answer is gravity, which is the same as the curvature of spacetime. In the early universe (after the inflation era) the distribution of matter/energy was very, very uniform and so spacetime was very, very flat. The gravitational effect of dark matter helped the small areas of slightly higher density to grow and thus form the kernels of the first stars and galaxies.

> Q3 Is this increasing expansion an acceleration?

Yes, latest measurements indicate that the [expansion of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe) is accelerating.

> Q4 Is it possible that space-time is not instant in its change in size or shape?

Oscillations in the curvature of spacetime caused by, for example, the merger of two black holes are called [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave). We know (both from theory and by correlating gravitational wave observations with gamma ray bursts) that gravitational waves travel at the speed of light.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I realize after reading your answers that some of my questions lacked a bit of clarification for my points of interest, particularly Q1 and Q3. I also attempted to better clarify Q2.